# What does it mean when a YouTuber says "Just don't touch!"?

Tags: phrase-usage

> Thank you for watching on air and on-line. And to subscribe, just click below, and comment and like, and just don't touch.

This is part of a YouTube [video](https://youtu.be/xCoxGV7j71c?t=8m40s) from America's Got Talent. What does the presenter mean by saying "Just don't touch!"

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's *such* a context-specific usage it's completely irrelevant to the normal use of English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to @deadrat....:

> The person doing the introduction is comedian Howie Mandel, who's gone public about his OCD and mysophobia (fear of contamination), which make him avoid casual touching like shaking hands. So he's gently making fun of his affliction.

So it's sort of a joke about his own medical condition.